# ngFormControl not binding correctly

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build a minimal example for ngFormControl since I cannot get it to work in a new component I'm writing, whereas in an old one it is working just fine and I just can't find the difference. Here is a minimal example where I get the binding error:

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {Control} from "@angular/common";
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input class="form-control" type="text"  [ngFormControl]="searchInput">
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {
  private searchInput = new Control();
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is also a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xlzK8bay3cPxl9xvnn7V?p=preview) showing the problem. From what I understand it should also work without importing the FormsModule, since FormsModule is only required for 2 way bindings with ngModel. Is that correct?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This way is deprecated in rc.3, you should now use ngModel.

You should have a look at this [tutorial](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html).

Comment: Hey, documentation doesn't say its depricated though: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFormControl-directive.html. The main problem why I don't want to use ngModel is, I cannot use the debounceTime and distinctUntilChanged methods that Controls offer.

Comment: You should have a look at this document https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/d/1RIezQqE4aEhBRmArIAS1mRIZtWFf6JxN_7B4meyWK0Y/pub.

Answer (score 1):

ngFormControl directive does not exist on new version(0.30.0) of Angular 2 Form

Following changes should fix your issue:

app.ts

```
//import FormControl from angular/forms
import { FormsModule, FormControl }   from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
..
..
//change [ngFormControl] to [formControl]
<input class="form-control" type="text"  [formControl]="searchInput">
..
..

export class App {
//change  new Control(); => new FormControl();
private searchInput = new FormControl();
}

//add ReactiveFormsModule to the @NgModule imports metadata
@NgModule({
      imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
      declarations: [ App ],
      bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/F1dXQEEkEDwcgqugQbUP?p=preview)